# Issue with a math rule of three in c++

Tags: c#, c++, math

I started learning c++, but I have an issue.

I'm trying to do a rule of three in c++ but I get a wrong result. Should give me *55.549,38775510204*, and I get *-41842.000000000000*

What I'm doing wrong??
In C# I do this and works fine:

```
decimal ruleOfThree = decimal.Divide(decimal.Multiply(32000, 76554), 44100);
```

In C++ I'm doing this:

```
long double ruleOfThree = ((32000 * 76554) / 44100);
```

Comment: `32000`, `76554` and `44100` are all integers that use integer arithmetics. You want https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal instead

Comment: seems like a typical overflow to me. your literals are integer-literals, like already mentioned, and the multiplication result of `2 449 728 000` is larger than INT_MAX `2 147 483 647` (hint: when maths in programming languages behave weirdly, split the calculation in several steps, then look at each partial result to pinpoint the error)

Comment: I see, and how could I fix it? The idea would be to get the same result that you could get with the windows calculator.

Comment: 32000 * 76554 is greater than 2^31-1 meaning its larger than a 32 bit int.

Comment: There is no standard C++ type that corresponds to C#'s `decimal`.

Comment: Doing audio by any chance? You can simplify the ratio to 320/441. Aslo, on an unrelated note, "rule of three" in C++ is a mnemonic that tells you that you sometimes need a copy constructor, assignment operator **and** a destructor, often none of the three, but it's very rare that you need only one or two. (The Rule of Zero says that it's best to make that somebody elses problem; most classes should rely on string/vector/etc)

Comment: @jms2505 *In C# I do this ..* -- Do not use other programming languages as a model in writing C++ code.  Today it's this issue of numerical types, tomorrow it will be something else, where you will be tempted to compare C# to C++, and it turns out all wrong.  Learn C++ as if C# does not exist.

Comment: You should include the FORTRAN tag because FORTRAN has ways you can do this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this on a C++ compiler, but something like:

```
long double ruleOfThree = ((32000.0 * 76554.0) / 44100.0);
```

I.e. make sure the 3 multipliers are doubles, not integers.

Comment: You can get away with only adding the `.0` to only one of the values being multiplied (in the inner `()`).   The `.0` produces a literal of type `double`.   Multiplying a `double` and an `int` works by promoting (implicitly converting) the `int` to `double`, then multiplying the two `double`s, producing a result of type `double`.   Similarly for dividing.  So your code initialises a `long double` with a value of type `double`.

Answer (score 3):

Just try your example and compiler explains what is wrong:

```cpp
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long double ruleOfThree = ((32000 * 76554) / 44100);
    std::cout << ruleOfThree << "\n";
    return 0;
}

$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:39: warning: integer overflow in expression of type ‘int’ results in ‘-1845239296’ [-Woverflow]
     long double ruleOfThree = ((32000 * 76554) / 44100);
                                 ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

The intermediate product is computed as `int` and it overflows.

Explicitly specify your data types to compute this in and it will work:

```cpp
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long double ruleOfThree = (static_cast<long double>(32000) * 76554) / 44100;
    std::cout.precision(17);
    std::cout << ruleOfThree << "\n";
    return 0;
}

$ g++ test.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
55549.387755102041
```

Read more on standard promotions and conversions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/standard-conversions?view=msvc-170